# Animation works the first time, but then

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Trying to animate a `SwiftUI` view. Works perfectly the first time, but then does nothing.
`self.pressed` starts out as `false`. I set it to `true` and then I switch it back to `false`.
I want to scale it up and then scale it back it down on button press.

What am I missing here?

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
        self.pressed = true
    }
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)) {
        self.pressed = false
    }
}) {
    Wedge(startAngle: .init(degrees: 270), endAngle: .init(degrees: 360))
        .fill(Color.green)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .offset(x: -100, y: 100)
        .scaleEffect(self.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
}
```

Basically it resizes my wedge shape when I press it, but then does nothing the next time I press it.

I did get it work with `DispatchQueue`, but it seems like a hack:

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.5)) {
        self.pressed = !self.pressed
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.5)) {
            self.pressed = !self.pressed
        }
    }
}) {
    Wedge(startAngle: .init(degrees: 180), endAngle: .init(degrees: 270))
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .offset(x: 80, y: 80)
        .scaleEffect(self.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
}
```

Is the second way the right way to do this?

--

Here is Wedge:

```
struct Wedge: Shape {
    let startAngle: Angle
    let endAngle: Angle

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        path.addArc(center: center,
                    radius: min(rect.midX, rect.midY),
                    startAngle: startAngle,
                    endAngle: endAngle,
                    clockwise: false )
        path.addLine(to: center)
        path.closeSubpath()
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your `Wedge` `SwiftUI` implementation

Comment: Ok, you say that something don't work, but don't say what do you expected to achieve, so let's step back, and explain what do you want.

Comment: I want to scale it up and then scale it back it down. The second implementation with Dispatch works, but is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you wanted this

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 3)){
      self.pressed.toggle()               // << here !!
    }
    print("B")
    }) {
 ...
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I scales it up, but never scales it back. I tried this too self.pressed = !self.pressed, same difference.

Comment: "This works, yet it doesn't." What does that even mean?